# How to move Top bar to left side in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this div that shows a **top red bar**. I've been trying to move this bar to the left side and make it look like a border left, but not having any luck. Does anyone know how to make it look like a **border lef**t using this code? Thanks in advance!

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: solid 2px #e1e4e8;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">this is a text</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please revise your demo to show your attempt. It's just a box that needs to be moved and resized. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: @isherwood that's my attempt getting the red bar inside the div but can't get it to show on the left side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example adjusted position of `::after` to make the red border appear on the left, hopefully close to the desired result.

```css
.container {
 position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: solid 2px #e1e4e8;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    inset: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class = "container">this is a text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `border-left: 6px solid red;` on the container class and remove `background-color: red;` from `.container::after`

Additionally, if you want to keep the grey border, just apply that style to each other sides of the container like so:

```
  border-top: 2px solid #e1e4e8;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1e4e8;
  border-right: 2px solid #e1e4e8;
```

See snippet below:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-left: 6px solid red;
  border-top: 2px solid #e1e4e8;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e1e4e8;
  border-right: 2px solid #e1e4e8;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class = "container">this is a text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just simplify it to a border?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: solid 2px #e1e4e8;
  border-left: solid 8px red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">this is a text</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a mixed border style and use hidden for the top, bottom, and right.
usage is described at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Comment: Please add actual code an not just a link only answer here (link only answers are not allowed/valid) since that link may later change or be dropped

Comment: See [answer] for tips and expectations.